# Most efficient way to build a serializer in C#

Tags: c#, .net-core, serialization, xml-serialization

I am currently building my own serializer and I'm at a point where I no longer want to misuse the `System.Xml.Linq` classes so I'm building my own.

Let's say I have these classes:

- XmlElement
- XmlAttribute
- XmlText

And let's assume these only have a `Name` property which returns `string` and a `Value` property which returns a `IReadonlyList<IXmlNode>`.

The question I have is, would it be more efficient to make the classes themselves responsible for writing out their own serialized value or would it be more efficient to have a class that uses pattern matching?

So for example **option A**:

```cs
public class XmlElement: IXmlNode {

    public void Write(StringBuilder stringBuilder) {

        stringBuilder.WriteLine($"<{Name}>")

        foreach(var child in Children) {
            child.Write(stringBuilder);
        }

        stringBuilder.WriteLine($"</{Name}>")

    }

}
```

Or **option B**:

```cs
public class XmlWriter {

    public string Write(IXmlNode node, StringBuilder passedStringBuilder) {

        var stringBuilder = passedStringBuilder ?? new StringBuilder();

        if (IXmlNode is XmlElement xmlElement) WriteElement(xmlElement, stringBuilder);
        if (IXmlNode is XmlAttribute xmlAttribute) WriteAttribute(xmlAttribute, stringBuilder);
        if (IXmlNode is XmlText xmlText) WriteText(xmlText, stringBuilder);

        return stringBuilder.ToString();
    }

    public void WriteElement(XmlElement element, stringBuilder) {

        stringBuilder.WriteLine($"<{element.Name}>")

        foreach(var child in element.Children) {
            Write(child, stringBuilder);
        }

        stringBuilder.WriteLine($"</{element.Name}>")

    }

}
```

Obviously there is more to writing an XML serializer, this isn't great code and I left out some parts here and there.
I'm mostly concerned about the concept of which would be most efficient.

**Additional information**

Since there have been some requests to define what I mean by efficiency here are some factors I'd like to score the implementation on:

- `Speed`
- `Garbage collection`
- `Memory allocation`

Of course code readability is also a factor however, at this point I've written both implementations and in regards of readability **Option A** has my preference. **Option B** resulted in quite some lines of code in a single file and arguably it's doing too much for one class.

So in short:
Unless **Option B** greatly outperforms **Option A** my preference will go towards **Option A**.

Comment: Define efficiency please

Comment: I guess in every sense of the word, Memory, Speed, etc.  
I'd like to weigh the different pro's and cons.

Comment: Is there a reason why you're not able to test this yourself?

Comment: Of course there is, I was hoping someone else might know so I don't have to build 2 implementations when someone else has already tested this.

Comment: But you've already written two basic implementations.  If the code in your question is sufficient for someone else to answer the question, it should be sufficient for you to answer the question.

Comment: @devlin that would only be true if every person had the same knowledge, which would make StackOverflow completely useless.

Comment: Avoid asking subjective questions where every answer is equally valid: “What’s your favorite ______?”

Comment: @ShrimpPerator : except this question is not one that is dependent on knowledge alone.  "Efficiency" is an entire realm of factors, most of which we aren't privy to.

Comment: Well you **can** define efficiency as a concept.  
Like for example if I have an IEnumerable and I split it into multiple select statements more without calling ToList() first.  
This can be called inefficient because the collection will enumerate twice instead of once.  
Anyway, I came here for advice. And the advice was test it yourself, so I'll get back to answer my own question when I have the results.

Answer (score 0):

In this case I'd suppose the answer would be **Option A**.

What I did to test this:

- I created basic data types for JSON and XML which would write out their own serialized value when `ToString` was called
- I wrote some tests that would compare the output of an expected string representation to make sure the output was what I expected
- I created a basic implementation of a serializer for both a JSON and an XML datatype
- I added test cases to the existing tests to ensure the output of both solutions was the same
- I wrote a basic [BenchmarkDotNet](https://github.com/dotnet/BenchmarkDotNet) test for both options and both data types and ran that with a [Bogus](https://github.com/bchavez/Bogus) fueled data input of about 200 complex items as an initial sample

This is the result of the benchmark test:

```
// * Summary *

BenchmarkDotNet=v0.13.1, OS=Windows 10.0.19043.1288 (21H1/May2021Update)
Intel Core i7-8750H CPU 2.20GHz (Coffee Lake), 1 CPU, 12 logical and 6 physical cores
.NET SDK=5.0.402
  [Host]                                                                              : .NET Core 3.1.20 (CoreCLR 4.700.21.47003, CoreFX 4.700.21.47101), X64 RyuJIT
  BenchmarkDotNet, Version=0.13.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=aa0ca2f9092cefc4 : .NET Core 3.1.20 (CoreCLR 4.700.21.47003, CoreFX 4.700.21.47101), X64 RyuJIT

Job=BenchmarkDotNet, Version=0.13.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=aa0ca2f9092cefc4  MaxRelativeError=0.01  IterationCount=1
LaunchCount=5  RunStrategy=ColdStart  UnrollFactor=1
WarmupCount=1

|           Method |       Mean |     Error |   StdDev |       Gen 0 | Completed Work Items | Lock Contentions |      Gen 1 | Allocated |
|----------------- |-----------:|----------:|---------:|------------:|---------------------:|-----------------:|-----------:|----------:|
| JsonDataToSTring |   420.3 ms |  42.31 ms | 10.99 ms |  19000.0000 |               4.0000 |                - |  6000.0000 |    232 MB |
| SerialJsonWriter |   420.7 ms |  58.03 ms | 15.07 ms |  19000.0000 |               4.0000 |                - |  6000.0000 |    232 MB |
|  XmlDataToSTring | 1,012.1 ms | 342.95 ms | 89.06 ms | 145000.0000 |               4.0000 |                - | 35000.0000 |  1,036 MB |
|  SerialXmlWriter | 1,128.5 ms |  70.71 ms | 18.36 ms | 203000.0000 |               4.0000 |                - | 40000.0000 |  1,384 MB |
```

The benchmark test was not extensive by any means and I did not do a very in-depth evaluation because these results to me are pretty clear.

For both JSON and XML **Option A** scores best on `time`, `garbage collection` and `memory allocation` on a pretty small dataset.

In retrospect, I could've seen this coming because C# doesn't support tail recursion.
In fact, when I increased the data size I managed to crash my computer by profiling code that overflowed the stack.

**PS:** I don't think it's valuable to go into too much detail of how the data is generated because such a small dataset already made such a difference.